# Editing in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: ajax, telerik, edit, radgrid

I'm working off of the following example to implement editing of a cell in my grid when the cell is clicked:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/editondblclick/defaultcs.aspx

I'd like it to work just like in the example, but based on a single-click.  I can't get it to work as I keep getting the following error buried away in Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource:

0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The string was not recognized as a valid format.

If anyone can lend any assistance, I will you owe you my first-born, as I am pulling my hair out trying to get this to work.

Thank you

Initially, the error was here but it didn't seem essential:

```
protected void detailsGrid_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        ((e.Item as GridDataItem)["detailsGridMonthOneCol"].Controls[0] as RadNumericTextBox).Width = Unit.Pixel(50);   // ArgumentOutOfRangeException - Specified argument was out of the range of valid values
    }
}
```

detailsGridMonthOneCol is the name of the column I double-clicked.  This didn't seem essential, so I commented it out and that's when I got the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 15, column 16485 in http://localhost:63919/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=;;System.Web.Extensions,+Version=4.0.0.0,+Culture=neutral,+PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:en-US:10a773fc-9022-49ec-acd6-8830962d8cbb:ea597d4b:b25378d2;Telerik.Web.UI,+Version=2012.2.815.40,+Culture=neutral,+PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4:en-US:bd12f06c-2391-4523-868e-0017245d9792:16e4e7cd:ed16cbdc:f7645509:24ee1bba:e330518b:1e771326:8e6f0d33:6a6d718d:58366029:4b09f651:a2c5be80:874f8ea2:c172ae1e:f46195d3:9cdfc6e7:2003d0b8:c8618e41:e4f8f289

0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The string was not recognized as a valid format.
```

The code is buried away but here's where the exception gets thrown:

```
var e=this._get_eventHandlerList().getHandler("endRequest"),b=false;if(e){var c=new Sys.WebForms.EndRequestEventArgs(a,f?f.dataItems:{},d);e(this,c);b=c.get_errorHandled()}if(a&&!b)throw a}
```

Comment: Can you post your code to this error?  How can I help you by looking at the correct source code without the error code?

Comment: And I went to that example after 2 minutes of load time, I can't click that example, but I think I understand what you want.  You want it display the input field so you can inline edit, then update the database on blur.  Correct?  If so, then post that code.

Comment: Hey Eric - I've edited the question to include more information.  I pretty much copy-pasted directly from that link.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: In the example, if you double-click a cell it should go into edit mode.  It's a bit touchy.  Yes, I would like to be able to click a cell, update the value and be able to save the value on blur

Comment: Did you saw this post? http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/error-on-gridnumericcolumn-when-using-columneditorid.aspx#1096359

Comment: You do know you can contact telerik support?

Comment: I suspect the data format used in edit mode is not adequate...can you post more information about the data formats used by your `RadGrid` and, if possible, your `OnItemCommand` function.

Answer (score 0):

In your Script Manager add a handler to the OnAsyncPostBackError="myScriptManager_AsyncPostBackError" and in code behind just put one breakpoint on the open curly brace of the method.

```
protected void myScriptManager_AsyncPostBackError(object sender, AsyncPostBackErrorEventArgs e)
{ // breakpoint this line.

}
```

doing this, probaly, this breakpoint will be hit and you could debug your code, and inspect who was thwrowing the exception.

This can help, but, the only way to help you, in fact, is if you provide the full source code. I suggest you to create another project, isolate the code that you want to work, and publish this code on github, ftp, etc.
Please, post your code and i will help.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not really buried away. Javascript is showing you this error. However. the error is happening on the server side (`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException`)

Check the Event Viewer (start => Run => eventvwr) it will show you more details of the error.